# Problem reading sql query in python 3 with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

Good morning.

I'm trying to read a SQL query with pandas through a SSH tunnel. It worked fine in python 2.7, but now, with python 3.7, it seems like the process paused when executing `pd.read_sql_query`. My code is the following:

```
def conect(lista, names):

    # Block of code where I set used variables below.

    while not success and retries < max_retries:

        try:
            print('Trying to connect ({n})...'.format(n = retries + 1))

            with SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_SERVER, 22),
                                ssh_username = user_name,
                                ssh_pkey     = ssh_pkey,
                                ssh_private_key_password= password,
                                remote_bind_address=(str_number, PUERTO),
                                local_bind_address=('', PUERTO)) as tunnel:

                engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
                        user  = user_name,
                        passw = long_pass,
                        host  = tunnel.local_bind_host,
                        port  = tunnel.local_bind_port,
                        db    = db))

                dic_df = {name: pd.read_sql_query(query, engine) for query, name in zip(lista, names)}

            return dic_df

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error...')
            print(e)
        retries += 1
```

I don't know if the problem comes from the engine or from the function pd.read_sql_query itself...

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hope you need a List comprehension name: [pd.read_sql_query(query, engine) for query, name in zip(lista, names)] in python 3

Comment: I'm not really sure about exactly how to use your advice. I test `dic_df = {name: [pd.read_sql_query(query, engine) for query, name in zip(lista, names)]}` and it fails cause, obviously, variable name doesn't exist, and also test `dic_df = {[name: pd.read_sql_query(query, engine) for query, name in zip(lista, names)]}` but it fails for invalid syntax...

Comment: read_sql_query Reads SQL query into a DataFrame. So are you trying to store this Dataframe as a key-value pair in a dictionary?

Comment: I don't see your point...In my original code I'm trying to store a DataFrame as value using a str as a key.